# Django urls.py not call the right view class

Tags: python, django

Here is my code:
urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', showGameLists.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('<pf>/',showGameLists.as_view(), name='platforms'),
    path('<pf>/<curDate>/', showGameLists.as_view(), name = 'pfWithDate'),
    path('game/<slug>/', showGameInformation.as_view(), name = 'gameInformation'), ]
```

view.py:

```
class showGameLists(FormView):
        ......
class showGameInformation(View):
    template_name = "showList/gameDetail.html";

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        gameSlug = self.kwargs['slug'];
        gameInf = getInformation(gameSlug);

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'gameInf': gameInf});
```

in the HTML page, I have a <a href="{% url 'gameInformation' slug=game.slug %}>
but it seems after I click it, he call the showGameLists not the showGameInformation.
I try to change URL to

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', showGameLists.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('<pf>/$',showGameLists.as_view(), name='platforms'),
    path('<pf>/<curDate>/$', showGameLists.as_view(), name = 'pfWithDate'),
    path('game/<slug>/', showGameInformation.as_view(), name = 'gameInformation'), ]
```

and it works.
But if I don't want to add $ at last, what should I do?

Comment: Put your `showGameInformation` in the second place

Comment: `<pf>/<curDate>/` can match `game/<slug>/` so the url is routed to the view specified by that. Order your patterns properly or make unique descriptive urls.

Comment: thank you! Solve it right now.